# SQLite database WHERE clause

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My `WHERE` clause is working in Lollipop but in Kitkat it returns nothing.
Can anyone tell me why?

My code:

```
   Cursor cursor;
   String[] projections={Detabase_info.NewInfo.PAGE_ID,Detabase_info.NewInfo.TITLE};
   String wherecause=Detabase_info.NewInfo.CATAGORY +"=?";
   String[] wherearg={catagory};
   cursor=db.query(Detabase_info.NewInfo.TABLE_NAME,projections,wherecause,wherearg,null,null,null);
   Log.d("file", "=====>>>>" + cursor.getCount());
```

It works in Lollipop but doesn't work in Kitkat.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Do you get any error in kitkat?

Comment: no .. i get no errors

Comment: Did you forgot to add tuples/records in the database in the device which runs kitkat?

Comment: try to run on emulator and check if you database is copied in the folder \data\data\packagename ,